# Why is synchronization not working properly within this code?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Over the past few days I have been reading articles about Multithreading and I have come across a simple task using multhithreading. This is the task:

Create an application which simulates the running race of 50 meters(in my code they are 10, does not matter). The number of runners should be 5 and you should name each runner thread. Print the winner. All the other threads should complete the race, as well. Print the time taken by each runner to complete the race and highlight the winner's time.

This is the code I've written:

```
public class Racer implements Runnable {
    public static String winner;
    public static int time = 0;

    public void incrementTime() {
        synchronized (Racer.class) {
            time++;
        }
    }
    public void race() {
        for (int distance = 1; distance <= 10; distance++) {
            incrementTime();
            System.out.println("Distance covered by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is " + distance + " meters.");
            boolean finalDest = this.isTheRaceOver(distance);
            if (finalDest) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean isTheRaceOver(int finalDistance) {
        boolean isRaceOver = false;
        if (Racer.winner == null && finalDistance == 10) {
            String winnerName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            Racer.winner = winnerName;
            System.out.println("The winner is : " + Racer.winner + " with time " + time);
            isRaceOver = true;
        } else if (Racer.winner == null) {
            isRaceOver = false;
        } else if (finalDistance != 10) {
            isRaceOver = false;
        } else if (finalDistance == 10) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is with time " + time);
        }
        return isRaceOver;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.race();
    }
}

public class RacerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Racer racer = new Racer();
        Thread a = new Thread(racer, "A");
        Thread b = new Thread(racer, "B");
        Thread c = new Thread(racer, "C");
        Thread d = new Thread(racer, "D");
        Thread e = new Thread(racer, "E");
        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
        d.start();
        e.start();
    }
}
```

One output is:

```
Distance covered by A is 1 meters. 
Distance covered by C is 1 meters. 
Distance covered by C is 2 meters. 
Distance covered by C is 3 meters.
Distance covered by C is 4 meters.
Distance covered by C is 5 meters.
Distance covered by C is 6 meters.
Distance covered by C is 7 meters.
Distance covered by C is 8 meters.
Distance covered by C is 9 meters.
Distance covered by C is 10 meters.
The winner is : C with time 12  // should be 11 ?
Distance covered by B is 1 meters.
Distance covered by B is 2 meters. 
...... and so on
```

The thing that bothers me is when it prints the time taken by each racer(thread) to cover the distance, it does not show the right time. I made incrementTime() synchronized, but the program does not work properly either. Can you tell me what is wrong? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each runner increments the time, causing an inconsistent state. You should separate the racers from the actual race, which should probably be in a separate class.

Your problem occurs in the `race` method of the Racer Runnable, where each runner increments the `static time` field, thus causing the unexpected behavior.

Comment: This explanation is correct. I don't know why it was downvoted.

Comment: Yeah, I know that the problem came from race() but few minutes ago I tried making a synchronized block inside the for loop and it seems to be working properly.. I ran it a few times.. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation, `time` is shared by all the threads. So, if one thread increments is, the other thread will read that value, e.g.:

- Thread 1 enters `race()` value of time is 0
- Thread 1 calls `incrementTime()` changing the value to 1
- Thread 2 enters `race()` value of time is 1
- Thread 2 calls `incrementTime()` changing the value to 2

This will leave the `time` variable in an inconsistent state. To avoid this, you can try delaring `time` inside `race()` method so that each thread has its own time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I had something else in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Every runner increments time and there is only a lock on the increments time method. Runner C finishes their race and calls the isRaceOver method. As c is going to get the time of 11, thread b runs the race method, sneaks in and increments time 1. As a result, c gets the time of 12 and prints out the time incorrectly. If your intention is for all runners to be able to increment the time, you have to make sure that only 1 thread is running race or IsTheRaceOver at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You would get same result without synchronized block since you synchronized an integer which is atomic by default. Synchronized keyword is unnecessary so there is no synchronization at all.

> Distance covered by A is 1 meters.
>   Distance covered by C is 1 meters.
>   Distance covered by C is 2 meters.
>   ...
>   The winner is : C with time 12  // should be 11 ?

From your output it's clear that another thread was incremented time too. There might be another thread which incremented time right before you print the winner. To solve your problem, you have to synchronize both `incrementTime` and `isTheRaceOver` methods this way you will make sure another thread will not be able to increment time right before you print it.

**But hold on:** Synchronized block does not guarantee updates are visible to another threads which is called cache coherence. If you don't use `volatile` keywords when one thread updates a variable, it's not guaranteed that another thread will see it. For example even if you set the winner another thread may still see it as null.

Make sure you use volatile keyword or locks (which also use memory barriers) to guarantee that the updates will be visible to other threads.